# rust - trouble importing module

Tags: module, rust

I have encountered a strange error preventing one of my files from importing a module
This is my src directory

```
src/
    functions.rs
    main.rs
    unit_test.rs
```

Here is unit_test.rs

```
mod functions;

#[cfg(test)] // only compiles on test
// make module f_test
mod f_test{
    // mark function as test
    #[test]

    #[should_panic]
    fn test_basic() {
        assert_eq!();

        panic!("oh no");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_add(){ 
        assert_eq!(functions::add(1,2), 1 + 2);
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn test_bad_add(){
        assert_eq!(functions::add(1,2), 1 + 2);
    }
}
```

When I try to run cargo test I get this

```
[vinessa@komputilo unitTest]$ cargo test
   Compiling unitTest v0.1.0 (/home/vinessa/Dev/Rust/unitTest)
error[E0583]: file not found for module `functions`
 --> src/unit_test.rs:1:5
  |
1 | mod functions;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: name the file either unit_test/functions.rs or unit_test/functions/mod.rs inside the directory "src"
```

Strange thing, if I add "mod functions;" to main.rs, cargo won't complain about that file, only for unit_test.rs

I am lost please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to declare `mod functions` in `main.rs`:

```
mod unit_test;
mod functions; // declare this module here

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I think you want this in unit_test.rs:

```
#[cfg(test)] // only compiles on test
// make module f_test
mod f_test{
    use crate::functions; // use module here

    // mark function as test
    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn test_basic() {
        assert_eq!(1, 1);

        panic!("oh no");
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_add(){ 
        assert_eq!(functions::add(1,2), 1 + 2);
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn test_bad_add(){
        assert_eq!(functions::add(1,2), 1 + 2);
    }
}
```

Additionally, your `#[should_panic]` is incorrect as it stands.

Obligatory link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html